# How to use List.ContainsAny to same effect as Text.Contains when excluding words?

Tags: list, text, powerquery, m

Currently have some code that works, however am trying to present it in a more concise way.
Code that works:

```
if Text.Contains([ColumnName],"apple",Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) and
not Text.Contains([ColumnName],"pie",Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) and
not Text.Contains([ColumnName],"cake",Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) then "Apple" 
else "Null"
```

Am trying to achieve the same effect as above code, but present it in a more concise format.
Code below can run, but how to adjust it so it can have same effect as above code? It should search for text strings that contains "apple" but excludes those that also contain "pie" and "cake" in the same text string.

```
if Text.Contains([ColumnName],"apple",Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) and
not List.ContainsAny({[ColumnName]},{"pie", "cake"},Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) then "Apple" 
else "Null"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for can be done with below code:

```
if List.AnyTrue(List.Transform({"apple", "pie", "cake"}, (substring) => Text.Contains([ColumnName], substring, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))) then "Apple" else null
```

You can refer to the [following video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXqRceLYlMQ) for detailed explanation on how to use this and also for an alternative approach.